# javafx background Task is not running more than once

Tags: javafx-2, task

The following is my Task initialization

```
        final Task<Void> vt=voiceTask();
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                new Thread(vt).start();
            }
        });
```

And here is the task coding

```
public Task<Void> voiceTask() {
    return new Task<Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            HelloWorld hw=new HelloWorld();// HelloWorld is simple .java class getting voice through sphinx
            updateMessage(hw.Hello());
            return null;

        }

    };
}
```

Now on clicking the btn Button for the first time,the task functions normally, but on clicking for subsequent times the task is not called.

I want task to be called on every click.
Please advice me how to modify my code to do so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

> As with FutureTask, a Task is a one-shot class and cannot be reused.

You need to create a new Task each time the button is pressed.

```
    final Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            final Task<Void> vt=voiceTask();
            vt.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
                    btn.setDisable(false);
                }
            });
            btn.setDisable(true);
            new Thread(vt).start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Actually i am using a microphone event whenever a task is started, now on pressing Button for the second time creates a new task, but microphone is occupied by the old task only. I thought to cancel() the old thread but that is also not solving the problem. Can you please suggest any way by which i can relieve the sources occupied by an old thread on terminate it completely so that  on pressing button again, the new task can use those resources.

Comment: The easiest thing is just to disable the button when the task is running. I updated the code to do this. If the task never exits, then that is a problem with your HelloWorld.hello() method, which is really a question about the voice library you are using, not a JavaFX question.